Power supply auto cut-off required when there is no audio signal
This is an add-on amplifier and speakers I've installed in the hourly chiming cuckoo clock and attached clock speaker output as an input source to PAM8403.

Source: Circuits DIY - Simple PAM8403 Audio Amplifier Circuit
All is working great with quality sound, the only issue is with a power consumption of PAM8403 as after hourly chime there is no audio to play around the hour and 3 AA D size batteries power this circuit and that last longs around 80 hours only.
So my question is how can I cut-off the power supply to this circuit when no audio is playing, and turn it ON when audio starts at hourly chime which plays cuckoo strikes and some music for around 30 seconds?

Source: Amazon - CentloT - PAM8403 2 x 3W Amplifier Board

Source: Sunrom Electronics - Stereo Audio Amplifier - PAM8403

Source: Mouser - Diodes Inc. PAM8403 datasheet

Clock PCB 1

Clock PCB 2

Clock PCB 3

Clock PCB 4

Clock PCB 5

Clock PCB 5 - With Details

The easiest way to turn this amplifier off (i.e. supply current <= 1uA) is to drive the SHDN input low. Though whatever timing circuit you use to do this will consume some power.

Can you please elaborate on how I can connect the SHDN? The circuit I have is the right-side one which doesn't have the SHDN pin connection

You may have to connect directly to the pin on the chip then.

Thanks for the insides, added 2 snaps of board and schematic which looks like SHDN is connected to PVDD to maximize the outputs

If possible can you please tell me what to connect directly to the SHDN pin on the chip, GND I know, but how we can connect it to turn on automatically when music plays?

SD = SHDN in your schematic above. Drive it high to turn off the amplifier and limit the current consumption.

As per the Datasheet: Shutdown Operation:
In order to reduce power consumption while not in use, the PAM8403 contains shutdown circuitry to turn off the amplifier's bias circuitry. This
shutdown feature turns the amplifier off when logic low is applied to the SHDN pin. By switching the SHDN pin connected to GND, the PAM8403
supply current draw will be minimized in idle mode. The SHDN pin can be left floating due to the internal pull-up.

Can we make it SHDN automatic when music is not playing I mean just after the hourly chimes, and turn ON back when hourly chimes starts again?

Sure, with an external circuit to detect input signal present or not and drive SHDN accordingly.

Yes that we can do and be thinking the same about having something externally to detect the audio signal and cut off the power supply of PAM8403, can you please please elaborate further and throw some light on how we can achieve the same

What would you gain compared to just using the SHDN pin? How much complexity would it add?

Don't know as it's a readymade circuit and it looks like the SHDN pin is connected to the PVDD pin to gain extra output likely

We can try somehow using the SHDN pin but I'm not sure where the SHDN pin should be connected to which will turn ON the SHDN mode when there is no input audio signal present

Gain to this circuit is the output of the existing melody circuit where the 8ohms 0.5w speaker is connected, I'm passing that speakers output to the input to PAM8403

So we need to manage the SHDN or cut-off the power of PAM8403 to sustain the battery power and life

How is the existing melody circuit turned on once per hour? Where does the original trigger come from?

I wanted to know that as well but as the clock is under warranty period I haven't opened the plastic case to see the circuit inside, so wanted to make some external switch which will turn on on input signal as the existing speaker starts the music and turns off when there is no audio input signal

Added Clock Schematics

@NayanPanchal - Hi, (a) You said that you added "Clock Schematics" but those were photos of a PCB (presumably the clock's PCB), not schematics. || Unfortunately reflected light on the PCB prevents reading some connector labels. That is where you could start to reverse-engineer the PCB to recreate partial schematics, looking for signals related to when the hourly chimes are played.

Added some PCB snaps without light reflection and added one snap mentioning all of the connections I'm aware of

@NayanPanchal - Hi, We can't do all the reverse-engineering for you remotely. Although there are potentially a few approaches, as I said before, I recommend that you could look for relevant signals. For example, of those signals you have now labeled, do any of them start (and ideally stop, but that is less important) at the same time that you want the audio amplifier to be active? What test equipment do you have? DVM? Oscilloscope? Can you build circuits from a schematic? Or do you only want an answer that is a pre-built module you can buy online?

Yes I want to turn ON amplifier only when labeled Speaker is playing the music I.e. there is a audio signal and PAM8403 is applying that audio signal and playing it well with 2 add-on speakers but when the music is over and the next music is about to play after a hour, I don't have any equipment to test but have LEDs, resistors and capacitors, I've all the equipments required to build a circuit and I'm able to make it if any Schematics is provided with components required, even I'm fine with any pre-built module I can buy online or offline is well suggested

@NayanPanchal - The lack of any test equipment means that it may be difficult for you to be successful. However in order for me to share my thoughts (and so I can then forget these details and not try to remember them :) ) I have written a braindump answer, explaining 3 approaches which I see as options for you to consider. If those details help you to move forwards, that's great. If they don't help you, but someone else wants to build on them to add more details etc. that's also great. If they are not helpful to you, then please ignore them :)

Thanks for your inputs and suggestions

How to trigger the PAM8403 audio amplifier module when the clock chimes
There are many details still unknown at this stage, but here are a few suggestions to help you - depending on exactly which approach you want (or are able) to take. This is a braindump and is not intended to be a complete step-by-step solution.
General Notes

As already commented, to reduce the power consumption of the PAM8403 when it's unused (i.e. for 59 minutes of each hour, if I understand correctly) your choice is either to remove its power supply (e.g. by controlling a P-channel MOSFET in its supply rail) or to pull its –SHDN pin low, during that time.
However, you should not have the PAM8403 audio input from the clock active (i.e. greater than +/- 0.3 V, see the datasheet Absolute Maximum Ratings) when the IC has its power removed. If you aren't sure you can comply with that, then using the –SHDN input to disable the IC for each 59 minutes is the better option.

The PAM8403 datasheet that you kindly linked, doesn't include a specification for the time between power-on and normal operation, or between coming out of shutdown and normal operation. That means any delay that the IC requires in order to become ready, is within its specification (as there is no specification for that parameter). You may want to test both power control options and see which method of reducing the power consumption has an acceptable time-to-ready value for you. You might miss the beginning of the hourly chimes, if the IC takes longer than you want before it starts amplifying the audio.

From your photos, it seem your pre-built PAM8403 module has not made the –SHDN signal available on an easily-accessible terminal for you. Therefore you will need to decide if the soldering and PCB track cutting required to detach that pin from PVDD and make it available (e.g. via a mod wire tacked to the PCB) is something you can do.


How to enable the PAM8403 when the hourly chimes sound
I can think of 3 basic approaches (of course there are options within each one):

Investigate using a pre-built "clap detector" module (or build your own), with its own microphone & placed close to the chime's own speaker, to detect the sound & generate a digital output when sound is detected. Use that module's output to drive a monostable set to (for example) 1 minute. Have the monostable output drive whichever method of powering-down the PAM8403 you have chosen (e.g. using the –SHDN input). Depending on exact component choices and signal polarities of the clap detector & monostable, a simple BJT or MOSFET inverter may be needed to drive –SHDN high when you want the amplifier to be active.
One example of a problem with this approach is that the amplifier might be enabled by any sufficiently loud sound in that area, not only by the chimes from the clock.


or

Connect directly to an audio output from the clock, via a variable attenuator, rectifier (if the audio input signal can go negative relative to the comparator's ground rail), comparator, and then again, take the digital output of the comparator into a monostable whose output enables the amplifier.

or

Look for a digital signal on the clock's PCB which changes state at the start of the hourly chime e.g. if one of the bird in/out or up/down signals that you labeled on a recent image changes state at the start of the hourly chime that you want to amplify (or even slightly before the chime starts), then use that signal (after any necessary conditioning / level translation etc.) to trigger the 1 minute monostable. Then use the monostable's output to enable the amplifier, using one of the options mentioned before.


Yes definitely was thought the same to add microphone controller but as the clock is installed in living room and it contains big output soundbar and other noises, so that is not feasible to have it, but the monostable option we can look forward, Yes Bird In/Out may work as trigger and labeled Swing Dancers may also work as trigger to 555ic Monostable, my quick question would be using speaker output as a trigger to 555ic?

When we connect LED to monostable with 555ic it glows but my question is if we power that 555ic with 3 AA D size batteries will it work and if we replace LED with PAM8403 power input will it work?, I know it's try and error exercise but asked if you have tried before or have some insights.

Hey I would be fine with any other amplifier as well which automatically shuts when there is no input signal or any other power efficient amplifier to play hourly chims in additional 8ohm 1w (2 speakers) and can be powered by 2 or 3 AA D size batteries or even with 9v HW (Hi-Watt) battery if it last longs for 2-3 months,  so we can remove PAM8403 add-on, the amplifier should be loud only there is no bass to play just a bird chims and dancing music

I'm fine with any pre-built or to build with Schematics, even we can have 2 mono power efficient amplifier as well...

@NayanPanchal - "the clock is installed in living room and it contains big output soundbar and other noises" This is new information, so I wasted my time explaining option 1 for the reason you explained. || "using speaker output as a trigger to 555ic?" You cannot use the speaker output directly in that way. I explained the circuit blocks I consider would be needed, in option 2. || "3 AA D size batteries" That's confusing. There are AA size batteries (really cells). There are D size batteries. I don't know what you mean by "AA D size batteries", although this doesn't change my replies.

(continued) "monostable with 555ic" I didn't recommend the 555 - a standard 555 would be a poor choice as it specifies Vcc > 4.5 V. Depending on what components you have available, you could consider one of the CMOS 555 versions with lower minimum Vcc (e.g. some work down to 1.5 V) and without the large current spikes of the original 555. || I don't have more time to invest in your project in its current state, sorry. There are just too many missing details. I hoped my suggestions would be useful for you to continue work on your problem, since you have the devices in your hands. I don't.

(continued) My approach would be completely different, by first analysing & reverse-engineering the original clock, looking for a suitable digital signal there, to enable the external amplifier. However as you have now explained that you don't have an oscilloscope, you can't easily do that :( || I wish you the best of luck with your project.

Agreed and will give it a try, firstly I powered it via 2 AA D-size dry batteries which lasted longer for 80 hours, and then I read the entire datasheet of PAM8403 and noticed they mentioned "The recommended operating voltage is 5.5V. When the PAM8403 is powered with four battery cells, it should be noted that the voltage of four
new dry or alkaline batteries is over 6.0V, higher than its operation voltage, which will probably damage the device. Therefore, it's
recommended to use either four Ni-MH (Nickel Metal Hydride) rechargeable batteries or 3 dry or alkaline batteries."

(Continued)  So now I've powered it with a 3 AA D Size Alkaline one, and now observing what time it lasts longs...

But anyways to make it power efficient I'm going to build a Monostable mode for a 40secs circuit with LMC555 and hoping that Bird Out will trigger the mode for Chimes and Bird In will trigger another 40secs for Dancing melody and it should work as we are expecting, Will give it a try on this weekend and let you know the outcome.
